# "The system cannot execute the specified program" on pip install

Tags: python, pygame, pip

I just installed pip using `get-pip.py` and now I am trying to install pygame.

```
pip install pygame
```

But it returns an error.

```
The system cannot execute the specified program
```

Comment: Google thinks this is an AppLocker problem- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2719305 This doesn't seem to be specifically about pip or python

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pygame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonrsharpe if you are using Linux, my guess is to try installing the dependencies for Pygame.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Hopefully this fixes your issue.

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: It's Filip asking, not Jon.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the location you are running the command from. You should not run it on the directory where `pip` itself is installed. Just run it at a top level just like you run the Python command.